# How can we evaluate clustering results from LSH cluster?

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, locality-sensitive-hash

I have performed clustering using [LSH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality-sensitive_hashing). I can compute the false negative and false positive probability, but I think that this is not enough to validate the results. I was looking into precision and recall but I do not understand how to apply it to clustering results?

I have tried to use t-SNE to visually plot the data, and I have gotten results which are quite similar to the clustering results. How do we justify that the results are correct from this?

Answer (score 1):

The usual cluster evaluation metrics are ARI and NMI.

You cannot rely on the cluster labels being identical to your data labels: clustering algorithms will label the data often simply 1,2,3,... with no particular meaning associated to each label. That is why there are other evaluation metrics in clustering.